# NixOS: how to import some configuration from GitLab? infinite recursion encountered

Tags: nix, nixos

I'm trying to deploy a NixOS VM while storing its configuration on a private GitLab repository.

My configuration.nix looks like this (simplified to only include the relevant bits):

```hs
{ pkgs, ... }:
let
  repo = pkgs.fetchFromGitLab { owner = "hectorj"; repo = "nix-fleet"; };
in {
  imports = [
    ./hardware-configuration.nix
    "${repo}/my-server-name/host.nix"
  ];
}
```

but it is giving me this error:

```
error: infinite recursion encountered

       at /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/lib/modules.nix:496:28:

          495|         builtins.addErrorContext (context name)
          496|           (args.${name} or config._module.args.${name})
             |                            ^
          497|       ) (lib.functionArgs f);
```

I do not understand where the recursion is happening.

It doesn't seem like its even fetching the repo, as I can put any non-existing names in the args and get the same error.

I saw https://nixos.org/guides/installing-nixos-on-a-raspberry-pi.html doing something similar without issue:

```hs
imports = ["${fetchTarball "https://github.com/NixOS/nixos-hardware/archive/936e4649098d6a5e0762058cb7687be1b2d90550.tar.gz" }/raspberry-pi/4"];
```

And I can use that line on my VM and it will build fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: OK, it seems the difference is that fetchFromGitlab is not a builtin while fetchTarball is https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/expressions/builtins.html#builtins-fetchTarball

Comment: So I'm trying to use the builtin fetchGit instead, but it's telling me "error: executing 'git': No such file or directory". I had hoped Nix would know it needs to install git to fetchGit

Comment: For my fetchGit issue : https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/3533

Comment: I'd still like to be able to use fetchFromGitlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recursion is as follows

1. Compute the configuration
2. Compute the `config` fixpoint of all modules
3. Find all modules
4. Compute `"${repo}/my-server-name/host.nix"`
5. Compute `repo` (`pkgs.fetch...`)
6. Compute `pkgs`
7. Compute `config._module.args.pkgs` (Nixpkgs can be configured by NixOS options)
8. Compute the configuration (= 1)

You can break the recursion at 6 by using `builtins.fetchTarball` instead.

Alternatively, you can break it around 7, by using a different "`pkgs`".

If you're using `configuration.nix` as part of a larger expression, you may be able to pass an invoked Nixpkgs to NixOS via `specialArgs.pkgs2 = import nixpkgs { ... }`. This creates a `pkgs2` module argument that can't be configured by NixOS itself.

Otherwise, you could define `pkgs2` in a `let` binding.

```hs
{ pkgs, ... }:
let
  # pkgs2: An independent Nixpkgs that can be constructed before the NixOS
  # imports are resolved.
  pkgs2 = import <nixpkgs> {};
  repo = pkgs2.fetchFromGitLab { owner = "hectorj"; repo = "nix-fleet"; };
in {
  imports = [
    ./hardware-configuration.nix
    "${repo}/my-server-name/host.nix"
  ];
}
```

Comment: `pkgs2 = import <nixpkgs> {};` works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: (for others who might want to copy the code: I have other errors in my config, like I forgot to put a `rev` arg for `fetchFromGitLab `, but they are easy to solve)